# (Python) How to upload files to dropbox folder using API withoud SDK

Tags: python, post, python-requests, upload, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload an image file to a folder in my drop box. when i request the Authentication i get a response but i'm not able to upload the file. this is how i do it:

```html
import requests

header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <Auth_token>',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path": "/home/Pics","mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
}

data = open(r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\1980.jpg', 'rb')

response = requests.post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload', headers=header, data=data)
```

I get a 200 response code but when i check my folder there is nothing in it.
What am i doing wrong?

response.json() is:

```html
{'name': 'Pics (2)', 'path_lower': '/home/pics (2)', 'path_display': '/home/Pics (2)', 'id': 'id:OVRvFsnXnNAAAAAAAAAAGA', 'client_modified': '2020-06-21T12:28:19Z', 'server_modified': '2020-06-21T12:28:20Z', 'rev': '015a89742f0558300000001d50ef150', 'size': 567987, 'is_downloadable': True, 'content_hash': '11ffddd183c5315d4195091c8b81f8efd57d3283d460d5dd6d5e782ea2616458'}
```

Comment: what is `response.json()` ?

Comment: @Tarique I updated the post with the Json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out what the problem was, In fact the file was actually uploaded but with an unknown format!

In the header parameters `"path": "/home/Pics"` "Pics" should be name of the file you want it to be saved as, like `"path": "/home/MyImage.jpg"`